# Select2 append new option text is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using the select2 plugin to select multiple users through ajax and in the same page I'm able to add a new user to the database.

What I would like is to after creating the new user in the database automatically append an option to the select2.

The plugin is initialized this way:

```
$('#users').select2({
    ajax:
    {
        url: 'ajaxFetchUsers',
        type: 'POST',
    },
    cache: true,
    templateSelection: function(item)
    {
        return item.name;
    },
});
```

And I add the new user this way:

```
$.post('ajaxAddUser', { name: name, email: email }, function(response)
{
    var newOption = new Option(name, response.id, true, true);
    $('#users').append(newOption).trigger('change');
});
```

As you can see, after I receive the response I try to add a new option to my dropdown containing the new user and selected already!

Although the user seems to be added it is blank as you can see here:
[image]

Comment: Can you console.log(name) just before you create the Option to make sure it is not undefined.

Comment: @ascsoftw returns the name without any issue. Besides, the name can not be empty and that is verified through PHP, so it means the option is not added if the validation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

The way I solved might not be the correct way, but I couldn't figure out with the Select2 plugin how to properly add a new option programmatically. The solution is to manually change the HTML with the help of jQuery.

```
var newOption = new Option(name, response.id, false, true);
$('#users').append(newOption).trigger('change');

setTimeout(function()
{
    $('.select2-selection__choice').last().html('<span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> ' + name);
}, 300);
```